# Developing a website for a kiosk

Tags: web, monitor, touchscreen, kiosk

A client would like to have a directory built website that will display on a large touch screen monitor / kiosk display (my guess is over 35" but flexible with the size beyond that). What I'm seeing online are solutions that just aren't quite there:

1. A monitor that displays digital billboard advertisements/menus/etc. Problem is, I don't have the resources to devote that much time to learning new coding and developing something akin to an app for this kind of thing. Plus, it needs to be interactive since it's a directory (think a small scale IMDB for local sports).
2. A smart tv or computer hook up setup with access to the internet. Problem here is that the user would have access to all sorts of websites and programs we don't need them to have access to (and may thus end up costing more for things we don't really need).

Is anyone familiar with something that might work by allowing me to code this into HTML/CSS/Javascript without letting the user deviate from the site itself? Maybe it's a combination of different hardware and software.

This has me really stumped. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions for this; generally you'll need to buy standard kiosk hardware (which will manage the touch-screen interface and normally include the PC you need), and then you simply install off-the-shelf PC software like [KioWare Lite](http://www.kioware.com/kwl.aspx) or [Provisio SiteKiosk](http://www.sitekiosk.com/SiteKiosk/Default.aspx) that manages the internet browser, on-screen keyboard (normally), and locking the user down.

You'll generally also need to lock down the Windows installation so it automatically boots directly into the software, and disable updates and other functions that will expose the interface to users. You should also lock down the user's ability to delete files etc. using standard group policy rules.

Answer (score 1):

Use Windows 8.1 Kiosk mode by using Assisted Access feature http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2013/10/25/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1.aspx

Answer (score -1):

The opensource solution which I work on for this use case is [Webconverger](http://www.webconverger.com/).

1. You buy the generic PC hardware, I advise you to thoroughly test the touch screen hardware before you buy, since many of them are quite poor
2. You develop the Web application
3. You [deploy Webconverger on the PC](http://webconverger.org/usb)
4. You configure Webconverger with the homepage of your Web application, perhaps with some [touch screen options](http://webconverger.org/touch_screen_calibration/)